# Count how many times I visit a thread

Tags: python

I have the following code which is counting how many times I visit a thread. The code is working fine, but I want to find out if that is possible to implement without any global variable involved.

```
import threading
import lib.logging
import time

count = 0

class Monitor(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, count):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        global count
        count+=1
        lib.logging.debug ("Count is: " + str(count))

def main():        
    for i in xrange(3): 
        t1 = Monitor(count)
        t2 = Monitor(count)   
        t1.start()
        t2.start()
        t1.join()
        t2.join()
        time.sleep(3)

    print "done"
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: How specifically do you want to track it?  There is `queue` and `pipe` for passing data between threads directly, and `Event` and `Condition` if you want an event-driven model.

Comment: Can we get a bit more information? What are t1 and t2? If you want count to not be global, you need to be displaying it at a level that has access to both the places it could be found. Ideally, if the print statement can be moved to the same level as the main function, and then add the field self.count to the Monitor class, there could be a function which checks the values of count from all monitor classes, and then prints the sum if it has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to count function call without global variable using `itertools.count` and python's function default arguments behaviour:

```
import threading
import lib.logging
import time
from itertools import count


class Monitor(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self, count=count()):
        # next(count) starts from 0, so to log first '1', + 1 is used
        lib.logging.debug ("Count is: " + str(next(count) + 1))

def main():        
    for i in xrange(3): 
        t1 = Monitor()
        t2 = Monitor()   
        t1.start()
        t2.start()
        t1.join()
        t2.join()
        time.sleep(3)

    print "done"
```

Here is a post about python's function default arguments: http://www.lexev.org/en/2013/python-mutable-default-arguments/

Comment: Thanks stalk, that is really an interesting one.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use a "semi-persisted" in memory counter.

For example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import threading
import time
import redis


class RedisCounter(object):

    def __init__(self, db, host, port, key, reset=False):
        pool = redis.ConnectionPool(host=host, port=port, db=db)
        self.conn = redis.StrictRedis(connection_pool=pool)
        self.key = key

        if reset:
            self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.conn.set(self.key, 0)

    def incr(self):
        self.conn.incr(self.key)

    def get(self):
        return int(self.conn.get(self.key))


class Monitor(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, counter):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.counter = counter

    def run(self):
        self.counter.incr()
        print("Count is: " + str(self.counter.get()))


def main():
    counter = RedisCounter(0, 'localhost', 6379, 'thread_counter', True)

    for i in xrange(3):
        t1 = Monitor(counter)
        t2 = Monitor(counter)
        t1.start()
        t2.start()
        t1.join()
        t2.join()
        time.sleep(3)

    print "done"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This might be an overkill for you, but a direction of solving such a problem nonetheless :)

Comment: Thanks a lot woozyking, this is really good example for the future reference but a little overkill for me now :)

Comment: @ilyaw77 you're welcome :) I generally apply this technique to applications that may need horizontal scalability, so I delegate out states/counters and such as much as possible to a DB.